# View com muitos, mas muitos case when's

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, view, case

Estou montando uma *view* no banco de dados que a *view* `pai` usa como consulta outra *view*, que por sua vez chama outra *view* (nessa *view* é feito a soma de vários itens e traz o total por linha), na *view* 'de fora' é pego as contas (por número) e jogo um nome para cada conta, exemplo:

```
case when conta = '1' then 'chamar desse nome'
```

Mas isso ocorre umas 30 vezes na *view*, já que temos várias contas, e na 3° *view* que chama esta, ele junta várias contas, mas usando o nome dado na *view* anterior, então fica mais ou menos isso:

`case when conta in ('alugueis', 'agua', 'luz') then ('grupo despesa')`

Só que são muitas contas, e muitos grupos, chegou em um limite onde o *SQL* me deu **limite de complexidade atingido**, sabem o que pode ser feito para corrigir?

Vou postar um trecho da 3° *view* aqui para exemplificar:

```
case 
when (a.num_conta between '1.1.01.001.0001' and '1.2.99.999.9999') then 'TOTAL ATIVO'
when (a.num_conta between '2.1.01.001.0001' and '2.4.99.999.9999') then 'TOTAL PASSIVO'
when (a.num_conta between '2.1.01.001.0001' and '2.4.99.999.9999') then 'TOTAL PASSIVO'
when (a.num_conta between '3.1.01.001.0001' and '3.9.99.999.9999 ') then 'TOTAL RESULTADO' end as 'TC',

case 
when (a.NUM_CONTA between '1.1.01.001.0001' and '1.1.99.999.9999') then '1 - ATIVO CIRCULANTE'
when (a.NUM_CONTA between '1.2.01.001.0001' and '1.2.99.999.9999 ') then '2 - ATIVO NÃO CIRCULANTE'
when (a.NUM_CONTA between '2.1.01.001.0001' and '2.1.99.999.9999 ') then '3 - PASSIVO CIRCULANTE'
when (a.NUM_CONTA between '2.2.01.001.0001' and '2.3.99.999.9999 ') then '4 - PASSIVO NÃO CIRCULANTE'
when (a.NUM_CONTA between '2.4.01.001.0001' and '2.4.99.999.9999 ') then '5 - PATRIMONIO LIQUIDO'
when (a.NUM_CONTA between '3.1.01.001.0001' and '3.9.99.999.9999 ') then '6 - RESULTADO DO PERIODO' end as tipo,
case when (a.tipo_conta in ('01 - CAIXAS E BANCOS', '02 - APLICAÇÕES FINANCEIRAS','03 - NUMERÁRIOS EM TRÂNSITO')) then '01 - TOTAL EQ CAIXA'  
   when (a.tipo_conta in ('01 - CLIENTES','02 - BANCOS CONTAS VINCULADAS','03 - TITULOS DE CAPITALIZAÇÃO','04 - ADIANTAMENTOS','05 - IMPOSTOS A RECUPERAR','OUTROS CRÉDITOS - CHEQUES DEVOLVIDOS','07 - MERCADORIAS EM TRANSITO ATIVO','08 - MUTUO NEWFER','09 - ADIANTAMENTOS PROJETO NEWFER')) then '02 - DIREITOS REALIZAVEIS'
   when (a.tipo_conta in ('DESPESAS EXERCICIO SEGUINTE')) then '04 - DESPESAS DO EXERCICIO SEGUINTE'
   when (a.tipo_conta in ('ESTOQUE')) then '03 - ESTOQUE'....
```

Comment: Não sei qual SGBD você está utilizando mas já avaliou o uso de CTE (Common Table Expressions) com WITH?

Comment: não conheço essa funcionalidade amigo, vou dar uma pesquisada pra ver, consegui rodar eliminando alguns 'case whens' desnessários, mas é como o amigo acima falou, quanto mais contas forem entrando, terei que alterar e adicionar mais condições e logo vai estourar novamente

Comment: Primeiro que você não precisa de between, pode pegar simplesmente os caracteres antes do segundo nivel (1.1, 2.1, 3.1 etc) e fazer uma comparação dirata. Por sinal me parece ter problema o formato que usou no campo (por exemplo, o que fazem os pontos dentro da string? se a largura é fixa, está armazenando coisa espúria, se não é fixa, o between não vai funcionar de qq forma)  - segundo que não devia ter essas strings no SQL e sim numa tabela separada (seja em SQL ou na sua aplicação). A resposta do @maniero os principais problemas na maneira que está aplicando sua lógica.

Comment: @RafaelS. A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 1):

Não era para usar `CASE`, deveria ser uma relação com `JOIN` ou alguma outra forma que estabeleça isto, em último caso usar uma *stored procedure* (isso parece errado ainda), inclusive porque isso não é algo fixo, se alguém mudar uma descrição, uma numeração de item, ter novos dados, ou sair algum, é algo discricionário do usuário ele terá que pedir para você mudar o código e se não mudar na hora a aplicação para de funcionar corretamente. A solução é pegar esses dados de uma outra tabela, e espero que já tenha ela, caso contrário tem vários outros problemas. Se não tem terá que pensar nisso, não pode resolver um problema de arquitetura e modelagem de dados ruim com uma gambiarra em código. Tem que ter uma parametrização desses agrupamentos.

O `CASE` serve para usar com algo muito estável e que nunca tenha que mexer, além de ser algo curto, você está transformando dado em código, isso tá errado. O ponto principal é que o `CASE` é o mecanismo errado, tem que arrumar a modelagem. Mesmo que tenha uma solução no código que não envolva refazer a modelagem será gambiarra.

Comment: Entendi, mas qual seria a opção então?

Pois nesse caso, não encontrei outra forma de fazer, pois eles precisam pegar contas ja existentes, agrupar e nomear os grupos, para entao trazer em um BI, hoje, não temos os nomes prontos no programa

Comment: A que eu escrevi na resposta.

Comment: mas ja utilizo de joins para juntar varias tabelas, o meu problema seria mesmo jogar varias contas, em grupos passados pelo usuário, pois a ideia é ter uma analise pronta, sem ter que todo mes pegar conta a conta, jogar no excel e montar isso, não consigo visualizar outra forma de fazer sem utilizar 'case when'...

Comment: A sua pergunta é sobre o `CASE`, e não tem como fazer isso desta forma. De fato não deveria fazer isso no Excel, tem que remodelar seus dados para que possa juntar tudo isso com `JOIN`, isso você não está está fazendo com `JOIN`, está fazendo com `CASE`. Eu consigo visualizar menos que você afinal você conhece o software que está trabalhando, eu não, só posso falar do que eu vi, e vi algo errado de se fazer, está usando `CASE` para algo que ele não foi criado.